# Running a Matlab program that includes ActiveX

Tags: matlab, vb6

I try to run a program in MATLAB (R2011a, 64 bits), the program contains ActiveX, but I get an error:

> In put PROGID does not represent an Activex control. if this PROGID
>   used to work before, please check vendor's documentation for
>   equivalent activex control progid

this program is fully launched in MATLAB (R2009, 32 bits)
I have instaled VB6.
Any help?

Comment: Post the code where you get the error please.

Answer (score 0):

You are running 64 bit Matlab and your ActiveX control is 32 bit.

Check out [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/271243-activex-progid-does-not-represent-an-activex-control-h-actxcontrol-uc480-uc480ctrl-1). It deals with the bitness needing to match between the Matlab version and the Ax control. If you are running 64 bit Matlab, then the ActiveX control should also be 64 bit.

You could alternatively install 32 bit Matlab.